# Build a Bluetooth gps receiver

Tags: bluetooth, gps

I am wondering if and how I can build a Bluetooth gps receiver that I can pair with my android phone to get better quality signal in the car.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it, use bluetooth dongle or the HC-05 Module for forwarding traffic of gps on pi to bluetooth transmitter.

so i guess you need a program which will manipulate the original gps values to usable and readble values

then send the value(gps manipulated values) to bluetooth.

Now either use UART(for hc-05) and bluez stack commands, you can use sdptool and rfcomm to make a bridge to send values to your phone.

modify this approch for better results .. ;)